# max() function gives wrong output

Tags: r, max

I have two variables 'y' and 'dose', and try to determine the max value from these two variable. However, when I use max(c(y,dose)), it seems it only recognize one variable. Similarly, when I use min(), it recognized the other variable. Does anyone has an idea why?

Thanks.

```
> y
[1] "4.3" "4.1" "4.1" "4.1" "4.1" "4.3" "3.8" "4.5" "4"   "3.9" "4.3" "3.9"
[13] "4.2" "3.9" "4.3" "3.9" "4"   "4"   "4.1" "3.5" "3.8" "4"   "4.1" "3.9"
[25] "3.9" "4"   "4.1" "4.3" "3.7" "4.4"
> dose
[1] "16.03" "16.03" "22.9" 

> max(y)
[1] "4.5"
> max(dose)
[1] "22.9"
> max(c(y,dose))
[1] "4.5"
```

Comment: What platform/programming language is this?

Comment: might want to mention what language you're using

Comment: There is a big difference between `max("character")` and `max("numeric")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are comparing character strings.

Consider...

```
max("apple","banana","banana2")
#[1] "banana2"

max( "1" , "2" , "10" )
#[1] "2"

sort( c( "1" , "2" , "10" ) )
#[1] "1"  "10" "2" 

sort( as.integer( c("1" , "2" , "10" ) ) )
#[1]  1  2 10

max( as.integer( c("1" , "2" , "10" ) ) )
#[1] 10
```

So convert your variables to `numeric` types using for example `y <- as.numeric( y )`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used class() to check my variables and they were characters. I thought I converted upfront, but apparently I didn't. Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: @user2929728 consider accepting the answer so we know the question is answered. Press the little green check mark next to my answer if you want to accept it (you don't have to). Glad I could help.